# Why I have random string at the end of variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(document).ready(function() {              
          setInterval(function(i) {
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
            var lastPostID = parseInt( divs[0].getAttribute('data-id') );
            var myurl = "/post/"+parseInt(lastPostID);
            console.log(myurl, "myurl");
            j.ajax({
              url: myurl,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                j("#temp").html(html)
                j("#temp").prependTo("#allPosts");
              }
            })
          }, 5000)
        });
});  
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div id="temp" style="display: none;"></div> 
        <div id="allPosts">
            <div class='post' data-id='100'>...</div>
            <div class='post' data-id='20'>...</div>
            <div class='post' data-id='1'>...</div>         
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see at console every 5s:

```
/post/100 myurl jQuery_div_update.html:12
OPTIONS file:///post/100?_=1392319636208
```

At first line (`console.log...`) is url ok.

But url that jQuery use (`url: myurl,...`) have at end "**?_=1392319636208**". Why there is random string there? How can I remove it?

Comment: That is because of `cache: false`

Comment: jQuery adds it to prevents caching.

Comment: It is to avoid caching, but a post request should not cache so it makes no difference. `cache: false` <--

Comment: It's a frequent question but I don't find any good question to close this one...

Comment: Lesson to learn from that: Don't use something you don't know what it's doing.

Comment: After i change it to ``cache: true``, it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your AJAX request you have defined the option `cache` as:

`cache: false`

From the jQuery docs:

> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
> cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
> correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
> "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
> other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
> that has already been requested by a GET.

And here is a link to jQuery Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If only everyone had access to this mysterious jQuery documentation you are talking about. Imagine people would actually know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It's the result of `cache: false` in your ajax option. see option cache out of [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).